# hello this program for calculate min and max in the array

Tags: c, arrays, function, max, min

I wrote the code with functions and it give me the address of the variable not the value in which the solution is in the same way of coding.

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbMRa.png)

and this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxi(int feld[],int size);
int mini(int feld[],int size);

int main(void){
    int feld[]={33,36,31,38,45,42,11,29,56,54};
    int len;
    int min,max;

    len=sizeof(feld)/sizeof(int);
    printf("Lange des Datenfeldes=%i\n",len);
    max=maxi(feld,len);
    min=mini(feld,len);
    printf("Minimum = %i\tMaximum = %i\n",min,max);
    return 0;
}

int maxi(int feld[],int len){
    int i,max;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(feld[i]<max){
                feld[i]=max;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int mini(int feld[],int len){
    int i,min;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(feld[i]>min){
            feld[i]=min;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: `maxi()` doesn't initialize `max`. Likewise with `mini()`. There are other issues as well (the logic in max and mini, for example).

Comment: You really should form your question in a sentence that ends with a question mark. It's hard to figure out what specifically you're asking.

Comment: Rather than post your output on some other site, best to post your output here and as text, not a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a starting value to `max` and `min` in the functions.
A good choice would be `max = INT_MIN;` and `min = INT_MAX;`. Also, add `#include <limits.h>` in your includes since the `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` are defined in it.

```
int maxi(int feld[],int len){
    int i;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(feld[i]<max){
            max=feld[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

**EDIT:** Your code also has the assignment of `max` and `feld[i]` reversed. I've fixed it in my function above.

Comment: why max = INT_MIN; and could I chose something else

Comment: @Mahmoud Abo Why would you want to set `max` initial value to anything higher?  Consider the array could be `feld[]={INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN, ...};`

Comment: it give me (Minimum=2147483637       Maximum=-2147483648))

Comment: when i revers it and defined min with INT_MIN and max with INT_MAX it give me the real value of min and max reversed .. so what is the solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to initislize `max` in `maxi()` and `min` in `mini()` first to some value in the array, say `feld[0]`.

Don't use immediate value such as `0` to initialize because using such a value will cause trouble when all values in the array are greater or smaller rhan the value.

Including `limits.h`, using `INT_MIN` for `max` and `INT_MAX` for `min` is OK.

**UPDATE:**

You are trying to calculate minimum value in `maxi()` and maximum value in `mini()`. You have to reverse the direction of comparision operator of `feld[i]<max` and `feld[i]>min`.

Using `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` is good because it  will also somewhat work when `size <= 0`.

**UPDATE 2:**

`feld[i]=max;` and `feld[i]=min;` are also wrong. They should be `max=feld[i];` and `min=feld[i];`.

Comment: it give me (Minimum=2147483637 Maximum=-2147483648))

Answer (score 0):

Code is backwards.  `int maxi(int feld[],int len){...  if(feld[i]<max){` should be `if(feld[i] > max){`.

Assignment also in wrong order.

Initialize `max`. [@munircontractor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726424/2410359) [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726471/2410359)

Similar problems with `mini()`.

```
int maxi(int feld[], int len){
  // int max;
  int max = INT_MIN;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    // if(feld[i]<max){
    if(feld[i] > max){
      // feld[i] = max;
      max = feld[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```